# how to merge two arrays into a struct

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, init

What I want my swift code to do is take the two arrays initilized in view controller and then move them into the struct added. I want to do the transfer in view did load. I dont know what I am doing so I put some code that I thought might be helpful but right now my code is not compiling in view did load.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var emptyA = [Int]()
    var emptyb = [UIImage]()
    
    
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        added.init(emptyA, emptyb)
    }


}
struct added {
    var arrayOne = //emptyA
    var arrayTwo = //emptyb
    
    
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want and not a struct with an Int and an UIImage property and then an array with this struct?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your struct like this:

```
struct Added {
    var arrayOne: [Int]
    var arrayTwo: [UIImage]
}
```

Then to declare an instance you would do this:

```
let a = Added(arrayOne: emptyA, arrayTwo: emptyb)
```

Also, it's typically good form to start the name of your structs with a capital letter.

Comment: Its states Result of 'Added' initializer is unused. How do I get it used?